# Meaning of the 2 different expressions

Tags: meaning, sentence

> If dispassionateness with understanding does not take place, it is
> vanity and pride that surfaces

"dispassionateness with understanding", this expression is confusing. Does it mean if only understanding doesn't exist or dispassionateness *and* understanding both don't exist, it is vanity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If calm empathy doesn't happen, the result is vanity and pride appearing.

Comment: does dispassionateness with understanding" mean calm empathy?